# Upgrading SQL Server 2000 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

please is there any checklist available for upgrading SQL server 2000 to 2012? What is your experience with performing this? Could be the upgrade performed directly at all, or will I need to go through 2000 -> 2005 -> 2008 -> 2012?

Thanks and regards, Matej

Comment: If you are that many versions behind a refresh install on new hardware followed by comprehensive testing (while continuing to run existing setup in production) *before* considering such a large change into production.

Comment: Sure, I'm currently in a planning stage. There are multiple relatively small databases managed by that instance (~40 GB completely) and we want to upgrade mainly because of new features in SQL server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 supports upgrade from the following versions of SQL Server:

- SQL Server 2005 SP4 or later
- SQL Server 2008 SP2 or later
- SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 or later

[Supported Version and Edition Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)